# Why is it one time のような and the other time のように (context: see text)

Tags: grammar

In this [video](https://youtu.be/tBkqfH-Eocg?t=225) at around  3m:44s she says:

～狩りというのは、いちご狩りのような、果物を自分で取ることや、潮干狩りのように、海で貝をとることに使うので、・・

Why does she use のような the first time but のように the second time?

My own guess would be that if we'd look at the clauses individually we have いちご狩りのような、果物を自分で取ること. So basically ending in a nound 取ること and therfore な is used. And then we have 潮干狩りのように、海で貝をとることに使う ending in the verb 使う and therfore に is used. So like an adjective, adverb thing.

But on second thought this sound stupid because 使う is reffering to both clauses, right? I'm probably overthinking this waaay to much and the answer is super obvious.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It doesn’t mean anything. Both could have been な or に.

Having said that, if anything affected the speaker’s choice on an unconscious level, it could be either of the following, or both.

1. There are multiple similar activities in the first category, such as ぶどう狩り, なし狩り, etc. いちご狩り is given as an example of them. Hence *things like strawberry picking*. In contrast, 潮干狩り is the only thing in its category, making *things like shellfish gathering* less natural. The adverbial usage avoids that.
2. The latter is simply closer to 使う, the main verb. いちご狩りのように in the first part would be understood as modifying 取る.

But that would be too much thinking.

Comment: I have a question: can I see 潮干狩りのように as to modify とる? I mean: in the original sentence, the phrases  connected by や should be nuon phrases, and 「潮干狩りのように、海で貝をとること」 being a nuon phrase means 潮干狩りのように should modify 海で貝をとる. Thank you for your answer!

Comment: @shepherd - Yes, you can.